# Multilevel generic repository with generic interface

Tags: c#, generics

I have problems with implementing of repository logic. In a real project I use Ninject, so I use interfaces for some classes. For now I made a very simple demo of the problem:

```
// ------- Base User -------------- //

public interface IBaseUser
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
public class BaseUser : IBaseUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

// -------- Individual User --------//

public interface IIndividualUser : IBaseUser
{
    string Gender { get; set; }
}
public class IndividualUser: BaseUser, IIndividualUser
{
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}

// -------- Legal User --------//

public interface ILegalUser : IBaseUser
{
    string VatNumber { get; set; }
}
public class LegalUser : BaseUser, ILegalUser
{
    public string VatNumber { get; set; }
}

// -------- Base User Repo --------//

public interface IBaseUserRepo<T> where T: BaseUser
{
    T GetById(int id);
}
public class BaseUserRepo<T> where T : BaseUser, IBaseUserRepo<T>
{
    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        // logic...
    }
}

// -------- Individual User Repo --------//

public interface IIndividualUserRepo : IBaseUserRepo<IndividualUser>
{
    IndividualUser GetByGender(string gender);
}
public class IndividualUserRepo : BaseUserRepo<IndividualUser>, IIndividualUserRepo
{
    public IndividualUser GetByGender(string gender)
    {
        // logic...
    }
}

// -------- Legal User Repo --------//

public interface ILegalUserRepo : IBaseUserRepo<LegalUser>
{
    LegalUser GetByVatNumber(string vatNumber);
}
public class LegalUserRepo : BaseUserRepo<LegalUser>, ILegalUserRepo
{
    public LegalUser GetByVatNumber(string vatNumber)
    {
        // logic...
    }
}
```

In this 2 lines of code:

```
public class IndividualUserRepo : BaseUserRepo<IndividualUser>, IIndividualUserRepo

public class LegalUserRepo : BaseUserRepo<LegalUser>, ILegalUserRepo
```

the compiler fires this errors:

> The type 'genericInterfaceTest.IndividualUser' cannot be used as type
>   parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
>   'genericInterfaceTest.BaseUserRepo'. There is no implicit reference
>   conversion from 'genericInterfaceTest.IndividualUser' to
>   'genericInterfaceTest.IBaseUserRepo'.    C:\Work\Tests\genericInterfaceTest\genericInterfaceTest\Program.cs  77  18  genericInterfaceTest

and

> The type 'genericInterfaceTest.LegalUser' cannot be used as type
>   parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
>   'genericInterfaceTest.BaseUserRepo'. There is no implicit reference
>   conversion from 'genericInterfaceTest.LegalUser' to
>   'genericInterfaceTest.IBaseUserRepo'. C:\Work\Tests\genericInterfaceTest\genericInterfaceTest\Program.cs  91  18  genericInterfaceTest

That happens only then I'm implementing the interface IBaseUserRepo in this line of code:

```
public class BaseUserRepo<T> where T : BaseUser, IBaseUserRepo<T>
```

Can somebody explain me please where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you intented to implement `IBaseUserRepo<T>` interface in `BaseUserRepo<T>` class, but what you did instead you constrained `T` should be of basetype `BaseUser` and also `T` should implement `IBaseUserRepo<T>`

Change this

```
public class BaseUserRepo<T> where T : BaseUser, IBaseUserRepo<T>
```

To this

```
public class BaseUserRepo<T> : IBaseUserRepo<T> where T : BaseUser
```

Now you've implemented `IBaseUserRepo<T>` interface in  `BaseUserRepo<T>` class and constrained `T` generic parameter to `BaseUser`.

Ordering matters :)

Comment: Sriram Sakthivel, I'm understood now what's going on there. Thank you very much for help!